# Difference between secret key and public key cryptography

Tags: cryptography, network-security

Difference between secret key and public key cryptography and also why secret key cryptography is more implemented and used?

This is an exam question that i have to learn on Network Security. 
Please mention the Main Differences and why the secret key is more used

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What have you done to find the answer yourself?

Comment: www.google.com and search the title. You will get lot of results

Answer (score 4):

**Secret key algorithms** are usually many times faster (like 100 or even 1000 times faster)  than **private/public key algorithms**.

Often both kind of keys are used at the same time. E.g. when encrypting a big file, you generate a **Secret Key** and use it for fast encryption of the file, and then encrypt the key with the **recipients public key**, so only he can decrypt it. This way you get the benefits of the **private/public** key algorithm (solves how to agree on a key), and at the same time get a fast encryption using the **Secret key** for the bulk part of the encryption.

This is e.g the way **PGP** do it.

Comment: While true (and important in practice) this is usually the *least* important difference from a cryptography perspective. It's like saying that the difference between motorbikes and cars is that motorbikes have smaller gas tanks.

Comment: Lets say you had an Private / Public key algorithm that performed just as well as a Single key algorithm in terms of speed, security and key length. What would the benefit be of choosing the single key version over the double key version ?

Comment: I think your answer is just fine, but the differences are more profound than just speed. One critical difference is the ability of public key algorithms to provide non-repudiable digital signatures, something impossible to do with symmetric key algorithms.